# Rails Postgresql Time Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone, rails-postgresql

I've got 2 Time Without Time Zone columns in my table (`start_time` and `end_time`).  When an event occurs, I need to see which of these columns has a `start_time < Time.now < end_time`.  The problem seems to be that Rails is not saving the Time in UTC and is instead saving the time exactly as I enter it in my field.  My local timezone is `UTC -5`, so if I put in an `end_time` of `09:00:00`, I would expect that to get saved to the database as `14:00:00`, but it's getting saved as `09:00:00`, so when I later run my `start_time < Time.now < end_time` query, I'm getting the wrong results (I'm off by those 5 hours).

Here's an example (the model is called TimeParameter):

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > TimeParameter.create(start_time: "00:30:00", end_time: "09:00:00")
   (7.0ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='time_parameters'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (9.8ms)  INSERT INTO "time_parameters" ("created_at", "day_of_week", "end_time", "start_time", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:29:06 UTC +00:00], ["day_of_week", nil], ["end_time", 2000-01-01 09:00:00 UTC], ["start_time", 2000-01-01 00:30:00 UTC], ["updated_at", Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:29:06 UTC +00:00]]
   (308.9ms)  COMMIT
 => #<TimeParameter id: 24, start_time: "2000-01-01 00:30:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 09:00:00", day_of_week: nil, created_at: "2013-07-23 14:29:06", updated_at: "2013-07-23 14:29:06">
```

Local time is ~09:30, UTC is ~14:30
Notice that the `updated_at` and `created_at` reflect the `14:30` UTC time but my `start_time` and `end_time` are not converted to UTC before being saved.

Ruby version: 1.9.3-p392

Rails version: 3.2.13

Comment: Where and why do you expect the string "00:30" to be a) interpreted according to your UTC-5 timezone, and b) converted to UTC?

Comment: I was hoping in the model creation it would take a string and convert that to a UTC backed time instead of directly interpreting that string as UTC.  I've set up my controller to now parse the string as a local Time object, it just feels hacky.

Comment: It's somewhat of a subjective question, and I don't know if this is the reasoning of the Rails developers, but to me assuming that an unspecified timezone means "current server timezone" is riskier than assuming UTC, as it means the code behaves differently in different environments. There is no reason for the code to suppose that the user of the site is in the same timezone as the server hosting it, so a user input of "13:00" is inevitably ambiguous.

Comment: It's a lot bit funky actually.  So the servers will actually be isolated from the internet and traveling around (think construction site) and then the info in the DB will periodically be synced to our home servers.  The idea being someone who sets up these time events won't understand UTC, but the computer/server will be set up in the local time zone.  This way, when a user says 14:00, I convert that to UTC and save it to the DB to keep everyone happy. Definitely not standard practice by far.

Comment: Something I found weird when using the time data type is that I couldn't convert it to the user's time zone like I could with a datetime.